# Create structs during nested loops and update them each iteration

Tags: c++, struct

There's 3 structs `X`, `Y`, and `Z`

```
struct Z{
    Z();
    ~Z();
    int c;
}

struct Y{
    Y();
    ~Y();
    int b;
    std::vector<Z> vec_Z;
}

struct X {
    X();
    ~X();
    int a;
    std::vector<Y> vec_Y;
};
```

and there's an infinite loop

```
while(1) {
    std::vector<X> vec_X;
    // stuff
}
```

Depending of the outcome of `// stuff`, the program will create a few instances of `X` and push them back into the vector `vec_X`. Then, the next iteration, `// stuff` determines whether more instances of `X` need to be created, updates the existing ones, and deletes those no longer needed.

Actually, the situation is more complicated than that. Each iteration of the `while` loop will yield a vector of `X`s, and each instance `x` of `X` will yield a vector of `Y`s (associated to `x`), and each instance `y` of `Y` will yield a vector of `Z` (associated to `y`), and each instance of `z` of `Z` will warrant some computation.

```
while(1) {
    std::vector<X> vec_X;
    // determine how many X's to create/update/delete, then iterate over them

    for(auto x: vec_X){
        std::vector<Y> vec_Y = x.vec_Y;
        // determine how many Y's to create/update/delete, then iterate over them

        for(auto y: vec_Y){
            std::vector<Z> vec_Z = y.vec_Z;
            // determine how many Z's to create/update/delete, then iterate over them

            for(auto z: vec_Z){
                // do stuff
            }

        }

    }


}
```

The precise number `X`s, `Y`s and `Z`s be created/updated/deleted needs to be determined each iteration of the loop; still, `vec_X.size()` is never more than 12, `vec_Y.size()` is never more than 10, and `vec_Z.size()` is never more than 5. There's no need for the container to be `std::vector`, since the elements don't have a notion of order.

Questions:

1. Every time a loop goes out of scope, all instances are deleted, and each iteration everything is created anew. How can things survive going of out scope?
2. How can I implement the **"create/update/delete"** idea?
3. All instances of `X`, `Y`, and `Z` should have "nonlocal awareness", meaning they should have visibility of each other internal's state. How? I tried to implement this through inheritance, but it led me into a circular hell.

My current code is inelegant and it's quickly becoming unmanageable. Is there a simple/natural way to implement this?

Also, here's a minimal working example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

struct Z{
    Z(){}
    ~Z(){}
    int c;
};
struct Y{
    Y(){}
    ~Y(){}
    int b;
    uint number_of_Z;
    vector<Z> vec_Z;
};
struct X{
    X(){}
    ~X(){}
    int a;
    uint number_of_Y;
    vector<Y> vec_Y;
};

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    auto epoch = 0ULL;
    uint number_of_X;

    while(1){
        vector<X> vec_X;
        number_of_X = 1 + rand()%3;  // Determine this programatically, each loop
        cout << string(79, '-') <<"\n" << "EPOCH " << epoch <<"\n";

        // Initialize each instance of X programatically
        for(auto i=0; i<number_of_X; i++){
            X x;
            x.a = rand()%10;
            x.number_of_Y = 1 + rand()%3;  // Determine this programatically, each loop

            // Initialize each instance of Y programatically
            for(auto j=0; j<x.number_of_Y; j++){
                Y y;
                y.b = rand()%10;
                y.number_of_Z = 1 + rand()%3;  // Determine this programatically, each loop

                // Initialize each instance of Z programatically
                for(auto k=0; k<y.number_of_Z; k++){
                    Z z;
                    z.c = rand()%10;

                    y.vec_Z.push_back(z);

                }
                x.vec_Y.push_back(y);

            }
            vec_X.push_back(x);

        }

        // Iterate through everything
        for(auto x: vec_X){
            cout << "x.a " << x.a <<"\n";
            // ... do stuff with the elements of `x`, in this case x.a

            for(auto y: x.vec_Y){
                cout << "  y.b " << y.b <<"\n";
                // ... do stuff with the elements of `y`, in this case y.b

                for(auto z: y.vec_Z){
                    cout << "    z.c " << z.c <<"\n";
                    // ... do stuff with the elements of `z`, in this case z.c
                }
            }
        }

        epoch++;
        puts("");
        usleep(2000000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. use pointers and heap allocation or better yet, put the `std::vector<>` outside the loop and clear it in the head of the loop. You can do that beautifully like `for( std::vector<X> vec_X; true; vec_X.clear() )`

Comment: @lorro Sounds good. Why would I clear the vector in the head of the loop, though?

Comment: for absolutely no reason :), my mistake, sorry. It's `for( std::vector<X> vec_X; true;)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll try to answer :

1. Regarding all instances being deleted. You can hold `vector<X> vec_X;` outside the while.
2. your second question is very unclear, what do you mean ?
3. If you want x,y,z access one each others members you can add public functions (Getters) or make x,y,z friends this way they will be able to access private members.

If you'll clarify question 2, I'll try to answer it.

Comment: Thanks! About question 2. Each instance `x` of X keeps an internal state, which is the value `x.a` and the internal state of each element of `x.vec_Y`. Each iteration of the while loop, we determine how many new X's need to be created/initialized. However, we also need to check which of the already existing X's should be deleted, and which ones should have their internal state updated.

Comment: For example, let's say that the first iteration we create 1 instance of X (and push it into `vec_X`). Suppose `vec_X[0].a` is `0xff`, and `vec_X[0].vec_Y` has 1 element, and `vec_X[0].vec_Y[0].a` is `0xaa`, and `vec_X[0].vec_Y[0].vec_Z` has 0 elements. This fully determines the state of our single instance of X. Next iteration, we determine this instance needs to continue existing, but now `vec_X[0].vec_Y` must add 2 new elements. Then, next iteration, we add even more instances of X... Anyways, I hope this helps. I can add as much explanation as you'd like; I just need some help :(

Comment: @DiegoAlonsoCortez I'm not sure I understand the problem, let's say (as you said) that "ext iteration, we determine this instance needs to continue existing, but now vec_X[0].vec_Y must add 2 new elements." In this case you can just do : for(int i = 0; i < numbertoadd; i++) vec_X[0].vec_Y.push_back(the thing you want to add);

Comment: Yup but if I do that I end up with a `vec_X` that grows with each loop, indefinitely. How can I keep it from growing without bound?

Comment: You can delete the unneeded items from the vector.